# When I group by it's creating 2 rows for each variable but I want one?

Tags: r, dplyr

After grouping by I want each variable on one row and merge the values above 0 in to one row ( and drop the 0 values ...  ie I want

CancerSites       y1994 y2018
All cancer types   518  828

What's the best way of doing this?  Spent ages on it :-)

````
```
library(tidyverse)

all_nhs_data <- read_csv("https://www.opendata.nhs.scot/dataset/c2c59eb1-3aff-48d2-9e9c-60ca8605431d/resource/3aef16b7-8af6-4ce0-a90b-8a29d6870014/download/opendata_inc9418_hb.csv")

borders_hb_cncr <- all_nhs_data %>% 
  filter(HB == "S08000016") %>% 
  select(CancerSite, Sex, Year, IncidencesAllAges, CrudeRate)

```{r}
incr_1992_2018 <- borders_hb_cncr %>% 
  filter(Year == 1994 | Year == 2018) %>%
  mutate(Year = ifelse(Year =="1994", "Y1994", "Y2018")) %>% 
 filter(Sex == "All" & IncidencesAllAges >=50) %>% 
   pivot_wider(
  names_from = Year,
  values_from = IncidencesAllAges,
  values_fill = 0
) %>%  
  select(-Sex, -CrudeRate) %>%
  group_by(CancerSite) %>% 
  summarise( y1994 = Y1994, y2018 =Y2018)
incr_1992_2018
````

```
[![screen_dump][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af7AB.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `select()` before the `pivot_wider` and everything is fine:

```r
library(tidyverse)

all_nhs_data <- read_csv("https://www.opendata.nhs.scot/dataset/c2c59eb1-3aff-48d2-9e9c-60ca8605431d/resource/3aef16b7-8af6-4ce0-a90b-8a29d6870014/download/opendata_inc9418_hb.csv")
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   .default = col_double(),
#>   HB = col_character(),
#>   CancerSiteICD10Code = col_character(),
#>   CancerSite = col_character(),
#>   Sex = col_character(),
#>   SexQF = col_character(),
#>   EASRLower95pcConfidenceIntervalQF = col_character(),
#>   EASRUpper95pcConfidenceIntervalQF = col_character(),
#>   WASRLower95pcConfidenceIntervalQF = col_character(),
#>   WASRUpper95pcConfidenceIntervalQF = col_character()
#> )
#> See spec(...) for full column specifications.

borders_hb_cncr <- all_nhs_data %>% 
  filter(HB == "S08000016") %>% 
  select(CancerSite, Sex, Year, IncidencesAllAges, CrudeRate)

incr_1992_2018 <- borders_hb_cncr %>% 
  filter(Year == 1994 | Year == 2018) %>%
  mutate(Year = ifelse(Year =="1994", "Y1994", "Y2018")) %>% 
  filter(Sex == "All" & IncidencesAllAges >=50) %>% 
  select(-Sex, -CrudeRate) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Year,
    values_from = IncidencesAllAges,
    values_fill = 0
  )
incr_1992_2018
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   CancerSite                          Y1994 Y2018
#>   <chr>                               <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 All cancer types                      518   828
#> 2 Breast                                 66    97
#> 3 Colorectal cancer                      63   117
#> 4 Colon                                  50    82
#> 5 Trachea, bronchus and lung             69   126
#> 6 Non-melanoma skin cancer              136   352
#> 7 Basal cell carcinoma of the skin       98   231
#> 8 Squamous cell carcinoma of the skin     0   121
```